# sub select inner jon "from tb1 t inner join (select a, b from tb2 where b = tb1.item2) as t2 on t2.a = tb1.b"

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, inner-join, where-clause

good day
I have the following query

```
SELECT 
    G.guid, G.guLastName1, G.guFirstName1, G.guShowD,
    G.guPRInvit1 as guPR1, GP1.peN as guPR1N, pl.pppo  as POST,
    pl.pppe, pl.pppo
FROM Guests G 
left join Personnel GP1 on GP1.peID = G.guPRInvit1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 a.pppo, a.ppDT, a.pppe FROM PostsLog a where a.pppe = GP1.peID ) as pl
ON (pl.pppe = GP1.peID) --and DATEDIFF(DAY,pl.ppDT,G.guShowD)>=0)
WHERE 
G.guShowD between @datefrom and @DateTo and G.gusr = @SalesRoom
```

the table PostsLog is a log of positions of the table personnel then i need the position of the personnel int the date range

but when running I get the following error

```
The multi-part identifier "GP1.peID " could not be bound.
```

can someone tell me I'm doing wrong. I'm not very good at SQL server and can not find my mistake

Comment: you are missing comma in between tb1.n and t2.a, but instead of that why you are making query so much complex, its just a join of table1 and table2

Comment: and you also need a period for t2b to be t2.b

Comment: and you need to re-write your title

Comment: Is `peID` a column in the `Personnel` table?

Comment: yes, is from perssonel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be your real problem:

```
                                                              -------VV
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 a.pppo, a.ppDT, a.pppe FROM PostsLog a where pl.pppe = GP1.peID ) as pl
```

the `pl` alias is for the subquery itself and thus can;t be used *within* the subquery

I suspect you meant

```
                                                              -------V
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 a.pppo, a.ppDT, a.pppe FROM PostsLog a where a.pppe = GP1.peID ) as pl
```

Comment: thanks but it was an error writing the query here in the real query this with a

Comment: @EzequielezzeklCanul That's twice now that you've gotten answers based on improperly rewritten queries - it's impossible to get a definite answer if you don't post the actual query.  Otherwise you're wasting people's time.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the subquery and move the condition to the `on` clause:

```
select tb1.a, tb1.b, tb1.n, t2.a, t2.b 
from table1 tb1 inner join
     table2 t2
     on t2.b = tb1.n and t2.c = tb1.b
where 1 = 1 ;
```

You had another error as well, missing the commas between `tbl1.n` and `t2.a` because periods are not allowed (unescaped) in column aliases.  Also, the `where` clause is superfluous; I'm guessing that you are constructing the query in code.

Comment: i post the real query